# SQL Server Login and Users?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I create a connectionstring to connect to the database, there are also users that i can create with specfic permissions for each database i have. If i can access that database by the connectionstring from my code without using any if the users created for the database then what good the users are ? please explain. thanks.

Comment: What connection string properties are you using? Do you have integrated security set to true?

Comment: not clear at all what you are asking. Aren't answers to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902766/implement-database-security enough ?

Comment: users assigned for a database dosn't mean login, how can i make user of the user if i can't login using it either in code or sql ?

Answer (score 2):

You can only access the database as a user.
It is not possible to use a connection string that doesn't have a user (or uses Windows authentication).

Comment: You could use integrated security where you doesn't explicitly specify a user.

Comment: @TomasJansson I think that would qualify as using Windows authentication.

Comment: @AndrewBarber oh... missed that part :). That is true, that is windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Auditing purposes is one of the uses of this. You know which users performed what if your tables store this information.

For example `SUSER_SNAME()` or `USER_NAME()` returns the username of the person executing the queries.

On ASP.NET using Sql Server auth, the username of the person executing the statements will always be the one specified in the connection string. For a Windows app using Integrated Windows Auth, for example, the username will be picked up from his domain account but still needs to be mapped as a user on the particular database.

Answer (score 0):

You normally use one of the users you created in the database inside the connection string. Unless you are using integrated authentication in which case you are impersonating a user and that user needs to be created in the database too. Either way you'll need a user in the database to access it through the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Just three quick benefits of separate users.

1) Direct access to the database:  If they're using SQL Server Management Studio (or similar) for ad hoc queries, you want each user to have a separate username and password.

2) Auditing: By using different usernames and passwords, you can log activity to specific users, so you'll know exactly who accidentally ran the command `DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS`

3) Security: Different users can be given different levels of access, so no one who shouldn't be able to CAN accidentally run the command `DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS`

Further, you can set up your connection string so that it accepts usernames and passwords (if you desire) such that your client application will still request the credentials from the user to verify what level of access they need (if such is appropriate to your application).